# Android : Click through Toast

Tags: android, android-button, android-toast

Upon clicking a button, a toast(with image) appears. This toast appears on top of another button. Now i want to click this another button while Toast is still there.
It takes some time for the toast to disappear. Meanwhile if user wants to click the button under this Toast, he should be able to. Currently Toast blocks it.

Is there a method by which i can pass the click through the Toast ?
Any other better approach ?

(I don't want to play with the timing of Toast appearing or disappearing..)

Comment: Also, i dont want to change the position of Toast. It has to overlap the Button.

Comment: If you don't like the way the `Toast` works, then use something else. `Toast`s are considered old school anyway since the user can choose to turn them off. My suggestion - just overlay one of your own views on top of your button.

Answer (score 1):

Use Crouton library instead of Toasts

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 0):

You can show the toast in a different location so that it does not get in the way of your second button.
You can achieve this by setting gravity for your toast.
sample-

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Toast` will never be clickable. Its not possible to get the focus of the `Toast` and capture a click event of any view inside a `Toast.

You can create a dialog for that to get the click event.

The API on the [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) class state that a toast will never receive the focus and because a toast is not a view there is no onClick message. I would assume that therefore childs of a Toast can not be clicked as well.

For more details check out [Use Image Buttons and Toast in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-image-buttons-and-toast-in-android/27680)

Comment: Seems like you're answering a different question. OP does *not* want the Toast to capture the click; it should go through to a button below the Toast.

Comment: ok...if there is an image in Toast and there is an button below that then how do i click the button?

Comment: @Nishant If the button is in the Toast layout then you can not click it.

Comment: Toast has no layout. Button has

Answer (score 0):

A toast can not be clicked. It is not possible to capture a click inside a toast message. You will need to build a dialog for that. Look at Creating Dialogs for more info.

The API on the Toast class state that a toast will never receive the focus and because a toast is not a view there is no onClick message. I would assume that therefore childs of a Toast can not be clicked as well.